# How to get records that between m records back and n records forward from a reference row - Non-sequential data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My scenario is as follows:

1. I have a reference record, say, **ProductId** = 1
2. The records each have a non-unique **ItemTypeId**
3. I would like to fetch records that exists between the following points

   - START POINT being 2 records BACKWARDS of type **ItemTypeId** = 1, from record of **ProductId** =1
   - END POINT being 3 records FORWARDS of type **ItemTypeId** = 1, from record of **ProductId** = 1

The query should **get ALL data** between the two points, inclusively

Here's a picture that illustrates this better than my words:

[image]

**How would I structure my query to do this?**

**Any better way to do it without temp tables?**

Thank-you!

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such things as "two records back" unless a column specifies the ordering.  Your table does not seem to have an ordering column, so your question do not make sense.

Comment: You are right @GordonLinoff. In fact, I did pose the exact same question to a more more SQL-proficient friend than I am. I do have a timestamp value and another Branch value that would make the question more meaningful. I will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for this to work at all, you need that record ID to be an actual column in the table. Rows have no inherent order in a table.

With that in place, you can use LAG and LEAD to get what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    RecordId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ProductId INT,
    ItemType INT
);

INSERT INTO #t(ProductId, ItemType)
VALUES 
    (5,1),(3,1),(7,3),(6,1),(2,7),
    (1,1),(7,3),(8,1),(10,3),(9,5),
    (11,1),(19,1),(17,4),(13,3);

WITH c1 AS
(
    SELECT ProductId,
        RecordId, 
        LAG(RecordId,2) OVER (ORDER BY RecordId) AS Back2,
        LEAD(RecordId,3) OVER (ORDER BY RecordId) AS Forward3
    FROM #t 
    WHERE ItemType = (SELECT ItemType FROM #t WHERE ProductId = 1)
),c2 AS
(
    SELECT c1.Back2, c1.Forward3 FROM c1 
    WHERE c1.ProductId = 1
)
SELECT #t.* 
FROM #t 
INNER JOIN c2 ON #t.RecordId BETWEEN c2.Back2 AND c2.Forward3;
```

Comment: Note that if there aren't e.g. 3 matching rows after, then "Forward3" will be null, and the query will return nothing. I'm not sure what behaviour you would expect in this instance

Comment: Wow! Perfect, James! I did come across LAG but, in my head, I thought it was an analysis services function. Nicely structured answer with a working example data set. +100

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do without using temp tables as you ask, the following solution work.
But it is not very nice i agree.

Well this is what i done :

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST;

USE TEST

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
ProductId INT,
ItemType INT
)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT
VALUES
(5,1),
(3,1),
(7,3),
(6,1),
(2,7),
(1,1),
(7,3),
(8,1),
(10,3),
(9,5),
(11,1),
(19,1),
(17,4),
(13,3)

DECLARE product_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT;

OPEN product_cursor

DECLARE
@ProductId INT,
@ItemId INT,
@END_FETCH INT,
@countFrom INT,
@countTo INT

DECLARE @TableResult TABLE
    (
      RProductId INT,
      RItemId INT
    )

FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor
INTO @ProductId, @ItemId

SET @END_FETCH = 0
SET @countFrom = 0
SET @countTo = 0

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @END_FETCH = 0
BEGIN
    IF @ItemId = 1 AND (@countFrom = 0 AND @countTo = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @countFrom = 3
        SET @countTo = 3
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @countFrom > 0
        BEGIN
            --SELECT 'INSERTION : ' ,@ProductId,@ItemId
            INSERT INTO @TableResult VALUES(@ProductId, @ItemId)
            IF @ItemId = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @countFrom -= 1
                --SELECT 'CountFrom : ', @countFrom
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @countTo > 0
            BEGIN
                --SELECT 'INSERTION : ' ,@ProductId,@ItemId
                INSERT INTO @TableResult VALUES(@ProductId, @ItemId)
                IF @ItemId = 1
                BEGIN
                    SET @countTo -= 1
                    --SELECT 'CountTO : ', @countTo
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @END_FETCH = 1
            END
        END
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor
    INTO @ProductId, @ItemId
END
CLOSE product_cursor
DEALLOCATE product_cursor
SELECT * FROM @TableResult
```

And this is the result i got :

```
RProductId  RItemId
3   1
7   3
6   1
2   7
1   1
7   3
8   1
10  3
9   5
11  1
19  1
```

But i prefer the solution of @James Casey.

By the way, why won't you use temp table ?